# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am create a authentication WebAPI.

in APP_Start Folder:

- WebApiConfig file:

  ```
  public static string UrlPrefix
  {
      get
      {
          return "api";
      }
  }

  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", string.Concat(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix, "/{controller}/{id}"), new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
      MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault<MediaTypeHeaderValue>((MediaTypeHeaderValue t) => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
      config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(mediaTypeHeaderValue);
  }

  public static void Login(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Login", string.Concat(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix, "/{controller}/{username}/{password}"), new { username = RouteParameter.Optional, password = RouteParameter.Optional });
      MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault<MediaTypeHeaderValue>((MediaTypeHeaderValue t) => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
      config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(mediaTypeHeaderValue);
  }
  ```
- WebApiApplication file:

  ```
  protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
  {
      HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
  }

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

      WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
      WebApiConfig.Login(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

      FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  }
  ```

I have the AuthenticationController in my controllers folder. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I have a few other APIs that work fine.

In the url I put the url I am entering is localhost:4453/api/authentication/user/pass. if I only enter user I get.

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:4453/api/Authentication/asas/'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Authentication' that matches the request."}
```

- AuthenticationController:

  ```
   public bool Get(string username, string password)
   {
        return true;
   }
  ```

Comment: Add the code for `AuthenticationController`. We need to know the methods.

Comment: I think it is my routing.

Comment: It will be more efficient if change to `public const string UrlPrefix = "api"`

Comment: I believe the easiest way to remove xml formatter would be `formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter)` if it's what you try to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to view true on my screen.

Comment: So you receive `{password}` as a part of the url in a get request? It's very insecure.

Comment: I know that. I am encrypting it. My friend focus on the issue lol.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for trying guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Global.aspx had to have this line

```
WebApiConfig.Login(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```